# ReactJS giving inst.render is not a function error

Tags: reactjs

I was showing a really basic Hello World with React and ReactDOM when I got a strange error `Uncaught TypeError: inst.render is not a function`. See it in this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/milupu/7/edit?html,js,output).

I've used React a lot, but new to ES6. Any ideas what I'm not seeing here?

The error seems to be saying that `Hello` does not have a `render` method, but I'm not sure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="
               https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.0.4/redux.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script>
const Hello = () => {
  <h1>Hi</h1>
};

const foo = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );  
}

foo();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was facing same issue. I was using React version **0.14.3**.
Upgrading my React version from **0.14.3** to **15.6.1** helps to remove this error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Original**

To use React with ES6, you need to inherit the `React.Component` class.

```jsx
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hi</h1>
  }
}
```

See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes) at its documentation.

**Update**

You can also use `function`, or `arrow` in your case. However you need to return the component.

```jsx
const Hello = () => <h1>Hi</h1>;
```

Notice the missing curly braces. In ES6, an [arrow function](https://notetops.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/es6-arrows-and-lexical-this/) without curly braces returns the result of its body expression.

Comment: Strange - the creator of Redux just uses `const MyComponenter = () => {...}` in this video: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-react-counter-example#/tab-discuss. How is that working?

Comment: Ah, you need to return the element if you are using plain function. (See edited)

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thank you for noticing :)

Answer (score 12):

`TypeError: instance.render is not a function` error comes when you don't have a `render()` function in your React component.

Comment: There was a mistype in the render function in my component case. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this error when a component I was rendering was `undefined`. I had never seen the error before. My app was also using redux.

In my case it was just a `<Book />` component in the `render()` method that wasn't defined.

So the fix was easy:

```
import Book from './Book'
```

My advice if you run into this issue is to check the render method of the container component and see if any components you are trying to render have not been defined.

It seems very strange to me, It should give the following error:

***Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Book is not defined***

Comment: This saved my time! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this! The error is not very explicit for this specific case.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error because I was accidentally calling `return someObj` in my component's `constructor`. Once I removed it, problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was used to getInitialState() and returned a state from the constructor too! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use an [implicit return](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html). Simply wrap the return of `Hello` component in parentheses instead of braces, like so ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/dufisa/1/edit?html,js,console,output))

```
const Hello = () => (
  <h1>Hi</h1>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was a child imported class; it had a typo of `return()` instead of `render()` -- multiple `return()`'s existed, just changed the outermost one to `render()`.

The clue was when everything rendered just fine when the child's element was removed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because I hadn't included the render function in my component (even though I didn't need any elements rendered)  - returning null seemed to work:

```
# doesn't work
class BarChart extends Component {

}

# works
class BarChart extends Component {

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any class component has to has **render()** method containing every returned content to solve this issue.

> render = ()=> {
> return (
> content)}

Answer (score 1):

I got this error due to spelling mistake. I was writing it as rendor() instead of render().

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. The return inside the Render was not proper.
Once tested the file directly with ReactDOM.render and making some changes got the issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i added the ***static*** keyword to the App component at the recommendation of webstorm/lint.  Try removing any ***static*** keywords.
`static App extends Component {...`

Answer (score 0):

```
const Hello = () => {
  <h1>Hi</h1>
};
```

is difference from

```
const Hello = () => (
  <h1>Hi</h1>
);
```

This is a common mistake, if you have curly braces `{}`, that don't return anything, in that case, you have to explicitly write `return <h1>Hi</h1>` But when doing Parenthesis `()` you don't need to return;

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a common issue for beginners. If you accidently put render() inside the constructor, this errer will come.

Just remove it & Solve It..