# Uncaught TypeError: inst.render is not a function; react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I am getting the `Uncaught TypeError: inst.render is not a function` in my React app trying to follow https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/

src/components/MapShowEmployers.js:

```
/* global google */
import _ from "lodash";

import {
  default as React,
  Component,
} from "react";

import Helmet from "react-helmet";

import {
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
} from "react-google-maps";

/*
 * This is the modify version of:
 * https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-arguments
 *
 * Add <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> to your HTML to provide google.maps reference
 */
const GettingStartedGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        ref={props.onMapLoad}
        defaultZoom={3}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 30.3, lng: -97.743 }}
        onClick={props.onMapClick}
      >
        {props.markers.map(marker => (
          <Marker
            {...marker}
            onRightClick={() => props.onMarkerRightClick(marker)}
          />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));


export default class MapShowEmployers extends Component {

  state = {
    markers: [{
      position: {
        lat: 30.4,
        lng: -97.845,
      },
      key: `Austin`,
      defaultAnimation: 2,
    }],
  };

  handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this);
  handleMapClick = this.handleMapClick.bind(this);
  handleMarkerRightClick = this.handleMarkerRightClick.bind(this);

  handleMapLoad(map) {
    this._mapComponent = map;
    if (map) {
      console.log(map.getZoom());
    }
  }

  /*
   * This is called when you click on the map.
   * Go and try click now.
   */
  handleMapClick(event) {
    const nextMarkers = [
      ...this.state.markers,
      {
        position: event.latLng,
        defaultAnimation: 2,
        key: Date.now(), 
      },
    ];
    this.setState({
      markers: nextMarkers,
    });

    if (nextMarkers.length === 3) {
      this.props.toast(
        `Right click on the marker to remove it`,
        `Also check the code!`
      );
    }
  }

  handleMarkerRightClick(targetMarker) {
    /*
     * All you modify is data, and the view is driven by data.
     * This is so called data-driven-development. (And yes, it's now in
     * web front end and even with google maps API.)
     */
    const nextMarkers = this.state.markers.filter(marker => marker !== targetMarker);
    this.setState({
      markers: nextMarkers,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{height: `100%`}}>
        <Helmet
          title="Getting Started"
        />
        <GettingStartedGoogleMap
          containerElement={
            <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
          }
          mapElement={
            <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
          }
          onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
          onMapClick={this.handleMapClick}
          markers={this.state.markers}
          onMarkerRightClick={this.handleMarkerRightClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've also tried like

```
const GettingStartedGoogleMap = () => {
    withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        ref={props.onMapLoad}
        defaultZoom={3}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 30.3, lng: -97.743 }}
        onClick={props.onMapClick}
      >
        {props.markers.map(marker => (
          <Marker
            {...marker}
            onRightClick={() => props.onMarkerRightClick(marker)}
          />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));
}
```

based on [ReactJS giving inst.render is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196988/reactjs-giving-inst-render-is-not-a-function-error)

The code is at https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/anthony-project-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put height is pixels

```
<div style={{height: '200px'}}>
    <Helmet
      title="Getting Started"
    />
    <GettingStartedGoogleMap
      containerElement={
        <div style={{ height: '200px' }} />
      }
      mapElement={
        <div style={{ height: '200px' }} />
      }
      onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
      onMapClick={this.handleMapClick}
      markers={this.state.markers}
      onMarkerRightClick={this.handleMarkerRightClick}
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: this causes `Uncaught TypeError: inst.render is not a function` and `Warning: NullComponent(...): No render method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define render, returned null/false from a stateless component, or tried to render an element whose type is a function that isn't a React component.`